# g++ 12.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) shows wrong line numers on compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

Ive upgraded my `gcc` on windows with `msys2` and now I get wrong line numbers on compiler errors.

Compiling

```
1 | int main() {
2 |  auto i; 
3 |  return 0;
4 | }
```

with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -g
```

results in

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:3: error: declaration of 'auto i' has no initializer
    6 | }
      |   ^
```

when clearly the error should be at line 2.

Calling `g++ -v` gives

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-12.1.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

Is this a bug in the 12.1.0 version of gcc?

Comment: Might be a newline issue. Check if the file has `\r\n` or `\n` line endings and try the other one

Comment: @Artyer Good notion.  On Windows, you would *hope* that `\r\n` would be the right thing to use.

Comment: @Artyer @Paul Sanders Thanks for the hint. Strangely it worked when setting the eol from `\r\n` to `\n`.

Comment: That's bad, I would consider submitting a bug report

Comment: @PaulSanders Will do

Comment: Reminds me of the "good old days" when the line number given with a syntax error could have been anywhere. *Syntax error on line 10191* in a 15 line file didn't really help much when troubleshooting.